# Is it possible to send a custom message to the WindowProcedure in Win32Gui?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I'm sorry if I asked something ridiculous (I'm a win32 noob) but I wonder if it would happen.Is it possible for us to change the message according to ourselves and process it in the switch (message) as in the code?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

      switch (message){      

          case WM_DESTROY:
              PostQuitMessage(0);
              break;

          case FindWindowA(NULL,"Task Manager"): // like this 
              //do something
              break;

          default:
              return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);

      } 

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `case FindWindowA` does not make sense. Although you can use a WM_USER message or similar for your custom message. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user)

Comment: The case values in a switch statement need to be constant expressions. The return value of a function is not. So no you cannot use anything like this code (even were you to replace `FindWindowA(...)` with something that returned a message identifier).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define new message:

```
#define WM_MY_MSG (WM_USER+0)
```

or

```
#define WM_MY_MSG (WM_APP+0)
```

Note than messages in the WM_USER + x range are private to the window class, whereas application-private messages need to be in the WM_APP + x range.
Than send this message to window with known handler (hwnd) using `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` API functions. 
And further process it:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

      switch (message){      

          case WM_DESTROY:
              PostQuitMessage(0);
              break;

          case WM_MY_MSG: // like this 
              // Do something, for example FindWindowA(NULL,"Task Manager")
              break;

          default:
              return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);

      } 

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Messages in the `WM_USER + x` range are private to the window class. Application-private messages need to be in the `WM_APP + x` range. Registered messages are public application messages.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, its correct. Have added update to post.

Comment: That doesn't help much. Window-class-private messages can only safely be sent in case they are part of the window class' public interface (like Windows' common controls). Application-private message, on the other hand, are truly private. Sending either type to an application (like Tast Manager), that neither has its top-level window class documented, or its application-private messages documented is going to fail. In a way that's generally not diagnosable.

Comment: So how can I continuously send my message to the window?

Comment: What means "continuously"? In a loop? Message to the window could be sent whenever you need (using `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` functions).